# Angular JS upload file occurs twice in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have a directive that handles uploading file and shows it in a list. For this I have a custom button for opening up the explorer. And after user selects a file from the explorer system shows the file name twice in the list. After debugging I realized it's calling the "onClick" method twice, once when the user clicks it (duh) and some mysterious event invokes it again. I think it's the scope.$apply part but can't be sure. Here's my code snippet:

```
<div data-ng-click="addFile($event)">
     <span class="icon-small icon-add"></span> 
</div>
```

Angular JS:

```
scope.addFile = function (event) {
    if (event.originalEvent == null || !(event.originalEvent instanceof MouseEvent)) {
              return;
     }

     if (!hiddenInputElementNode) {
       //inject the hidden HtmlInputFile element and bind to the click event
       hiddenInputElementNode = angular.element(
       "<input accept='application/pdf,audio/*' type='file' class='hidden' multiple />");

       hiddenInputElementNode.insertAfter(event.target);
     }
     //bind to the inputElementNode change event 
     hiddenInputElementNode.bind('change', function () {
       angular.forEach(hiddenInputElementNode[0].files, function (dataFile) {
       scope.$apply(
              scope.selectedFiles.push({
              name: dataFile.name,
              data: dataFile
              }));
       });
       this.value = null;
       hiddenInputElementNode.unbind('change');
     });

     $timeout(function () {
       if (!!hiddenInputElementNode) {
         hiddenInputElementNode.click();
       }
     }, 0, false);
  };
```

Even weirder `this.value = null` doesn't nullify the value!

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing your javascript code for this one:

```
scope.addFile = function (event) {
    if (event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() === "DIV") {

        if (!hiddenInputElementNode) {
            //inject the hidden HtmlInputFile element and bind to the click event
            hiddenInputElementNode = angular.element(
            "<input accept='application/pdf,audio/*' type='file' class='hidden' multiple />");

            hiddenInputElementNode.insertAfter(event.target);
        }
        //bind to the inputElementNode change event 
        hiddenInputElementNode.bind('change', function () {
            angular.forEach(hiddenInputElementNode[0].files, function (dataFile) {
                scope.$apply(
                        scope.selectedFiles.push({
                            name: dataFile.name,
                            data: dataFile
                        }));
            });
            this.value = null;
            hiddenInputElementNode.unbind('change');
        });

        $timeout(function () {
            if (!!hiddenInputElementNode) {
                hiddenInputElementNode.click();
            }
        }, 0, false);
    }
};
```

I believe that you ng-click event is been fired twice because of the span inside the div (i had a similar problem with IE too).

Comment: I went with checking event.originalEvent for IE although that's a non-standard property. For some reason my target.tagName was Span.

Comment: So, the original problem persists?